# Windows Server 2003 Sharing files to DOS

Tags: windows-server-2003, ms-dos

I'm having situation like this:

I have a machine, whitch uses MS-DOS to get data how to build things and so on. I Have installed TCP/IP client, drivers for network card and other stuff required to use TCP. My goal that that MS-DOS machine can reach and get data from Server 2003 R2 over TCP/IP

My problem:

When I try to map a disk form 2003 R2 server is says access denied and I can't find any configurations for this. Maybe you know how to give access for it?

I can ping Server 2003 R2 and reach

Comment: By the way, I am using ACTIVE DIRECTORY in Server 2003 R2, and I'm trying to get data from server by one user form A D

Comment: How are you currently mapping the drive? Are you including a domain username and password in the command?

Comment: I'm using **NET USE F: \\ADDRES\To\FOLDER**

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using net use and include the credentials. Something like this.

```
Net use F: \\Address\To\Folder Password /user:Domain\Username
```

Comment: No luck, says /user:... option unknown

Comment: If you type
    "net use /?"
What does it display? Any reference to /user:?

Also, try mapping to the share only and not to a folder inside the share... See if you get the same results.

Comment: I created a DOS 6.22 VM to test with and it appears as though NET.EXE in 6.22 does not support the /user option... Looking for an alternative though.

Comment: Yes, it dosn't understand /user in DOS 6.22